# Localized NIB not loading the localized version of image in XCode4

Tags: objective-c, localization, uiimage, xcode4.2, nib

I noticed an issue in XCode 4.2 where some localized NIBs don't load the correct image from their respective language bundle.

In one of my controllers, I have several image views.  In the English version, I have noticed that some image views grab the french version of the images that are supposed to be loaded on them. The same thing happens to the French version of the NIB.

I have obviously double-checked my image resources and verified that the french images are correctly stored in both the "en.lproj" and "fr.lproj" folders.

Has anyone run into this issue before?  The biggest head-scratcher is everytime I run the project, whether in the simulator or the actual phone, the images seem to flip-flop consistently.  I don't even have manual calls in my controller to load images. All images are just preset via the NIB.

Comment: Does that problem always occur with the same images?

Comment: At first I thought yes. I have tried recreating the NIBs and manually adding the localized images. For a while the images would load fine in the NIB when I open it in IB. As soon as I run the project, the simulator/iPhone build would only load some images properly. As soon as I open the affected NIB in XCode, some of the images now appear in french (other image views are not affected though). The affected image views are also random. I am really very close to just doing manual calls in my code to load the correct image. :-(

Comment: I ended up manually writing load methods in my viewWillAppear delegate. :-(

Answer (score 0):

If you localized a resource after it was included in a build, the unlocalized version of the resource remains in the built application. Rebuilding the application only adds new files and updates edited files but don't remove deleted files.

To solve that problem in the simulator, you can open the Organizer (`Window` > `Organizer`), select the `Projects` tab and delete your project's derived data, then rebuild.

To solve that problem on your device, you can delete the application, clean your build products (`Product` > `Clean`), then rebuild.

Comment: Hi Nicolas, I just tried the Organizer > Projects > Delete derived data approach. That didn't work. I have also deleted the actual app from the device numerous times (I practically do a fresh build everytime in the device and simulator). Still no luck either :-(

Comment: I'm just curious, if I localize a NIB, it should technically be loading the localized version of the image too right? i.e. I should see the french version of my nib loading the french images, correct?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and the only solution I have found was to remove the images localization and load them.

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:NSLocalizedString (@"imageOne.png", @"Main Image")];
```

And in your *Localizble.strings (Spanish)* for example, you write:

```
"imageOne.png" = "imageOne_es.png";
```

And for *Localizble.strings (English)*:

```
"imageOne.png" = "imageOne_en.png";
```